# Socket.Disconnect выбрасывает ли исключение при неподключенном сокете?

Tags: c#, .net, сокет, клиент-сервер, tcp-ip

Имеется простой синхронный TCP-клиент-сервер "запрос-ответ", написанный на скорую руку, но, как я думал, вполне надежный - там и обработка Read() = 0, и все try-catch'и на Connect, Read и Write, и даже на AcceptTcpClient.

Недели 2 сервер исправно работал, хотя клиенты - мобильные, и там особенно часто бывают проблемы с сетью.

Но вот на Disconnect, который вызывается сервером уже в catchах (в каждом catchе), никакого try-catch не было. И даже не было логирования после каждого Disconnect - из-за чего теперь не могу понять, в Disconnect ли проблема, или она уже после этого, когда цикл уходит на новый Accept. (Процесс уже завершен - procdump не предлагать)

Дословно, код на сервере по возврату ответа выглядел так:

```
try
{
    client.GetStream().Write(msResp.ToArray(), 0, (int)msResp.Length);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log(cip + "ERROR: Cannot write response");
    log(ex);
    client.Client.Disconnect(true); //TODO try-catch
    continue; //уходим на accept нового
}
```

Try-catch только TODO :)

Ранее все ошибки были типа "тайм-аут" (на сервере стоит жесткий ReceiveTimeout для каждого клиента), и были они не в Write, а в Read, и хотя там тоже не было try-catch на Disconnect - все было нормально.

А вот сегодня в логе появилась сессия с ошибкой типа "операция невозможна не неподключенных сокетах" на Write, эту ошибку сервер исправно залогировал... и упал. Отсюда и вывод, что сам Disconnect в таком случае тоже надо в try-catch.

Но [документация MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket.disconnect(v=vs.110).aspx) не содержит четкого ответа на такой вопрос, а самому проверять некогда.

Comment: Вы задали вопрос 14 часов назад. Неужели за это время вы бы не успели написать тестовое приложение, которое пытается закрыть неоткрытый сокет?

Comment: @VladD Есть проекты, а есть проекты.